# How to pass checkbox values to an ACTION_SEND

Tags: java, android, email, checkbox

I'm trying to do my first app, I'm self-taught in Java and I started 2 month ago so please forgive my errors.
I want to pass the CheckBoxes values to an email text but I think I need to refresh "something" before sending the email because the values are always false..and I don't know how can I do.
Here is the code:

```
public class Appuntamento extends Activity{
    String paziente;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.appuntamento);
        //riceviamo id e lo mettiamo come nome utente
        final EditText nomePaziente = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nomePaziente);
        Bundle dati = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        nomePaziente.setText(dati.getString("id"));
        final String id = dati.getString("id");
        EditText noteAppuntamento = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noteAppuntamento);
        final String note = noteAppuntamento.getText().toString();

        final CheckBox lunedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxLunedi);
        final boolean lun = lunedi.isSelected();
        final CheckBox martedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxMartedì);
        final boolean mar = martedi.isSelected();
        final CheckBox mercoledi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxMercoledi);
        final boolean mer = mercoledi.isSelected();
        final CheckBox giovedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxGiovedi);
        final boolean giov = giovedi.isSelected();
        final CheckBox venerdi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxVenerdi);
        final boolean ven = venerdi.isSelected();


        StringBuilder testoMail = new StringBuilder();
        if (lun ){
            testoMail.append("Lunedì");
        } else if (mar){
            testoMail.append("Martedì");
        }else if (mer) {
            testoMail.append("Mercoledì");
        } else if (giov) {
            testoMail.append("Giovedì");
        } else if (ven) {
            testoMail.append("Venerdì");
        }

        final String giorni = testoMail.toString();


        Button richiestaAppuntamento = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRichiestaAppuntamento);
        richiestaAppuntamento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                mail.setType("message/rfc822");
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Richiesta appuntamento");
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Nome paziente: " + id + " " + giorni + " " + "Note: " + note);
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"dottcastellitto@gmail.com"});
                startActivity(mail);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two way you can do this one 
like

```
public class Appuntamento extends Activity
{ 
String paziente;
  boolean lun,mar ,mer,giov,ven;
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.appuntamento);
    //riceviamo id e lo mettiamo come nome utente
    final EditText nomePaziente = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nomePaziente);
    Bundle dati = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    nomePaziente.setText(dati.getString("id"));
    final String id = dati.getString("id");
    EditText noteAppuntamento = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noteAppuntamento);
    final String note = noteAppuntamento.getText().toString();

    final CheckBox lunedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxLunedi);

    final CheckBox martedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxMartedì);

    final CheckBox mercoledi =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxMercoledi);

    final CheckBox giovedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxGiovedi);

    final CheckBox venerdi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxVenerdi); 
    Button richiestaAppuntamento =   (Button)     findViewById(R.id.btnRichiestaAppuntamento);
    richiestaAppuntamento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ven = venerdi.isChecked();
        lun = lunedi.isChecked();
        mar = martedi.isChecked();
        mer = mercoledi.isChecked();
        giov = giovedi.isChecked();
        StringBuilder testoMail = new StringBuilder();
//your code this is fine if only one selected item info or data you want to send in mail 
        if (lun ){
         testoMail.append("Lunedì");
        } else if (mar){
          testoMail.append("Martedì");
        }else if (mer) {
         testoMail.append("Mercoledì");
        } else if (giov) {
         testoMail.append("Giovedì");
        } else if (ven) {
         testoMail.append("Venerdì");
        }
// if you want all then comment above code and uncomment below code
/*
            if (lun ){
             testoMail.append("Lunedì");
            } 
            if (mar){
              testoMail.append("Martedì");
            }
            if (mer) {
             testoMail.append("Mercoledì");
            } 
            if (giov) {
             testoMail.append("Giovedì");
            } 
            if (ven) {
             testoMail.append("Venerdì");
            }
*/

      String giorni = testoMail.toString();
            Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            mail.setType("message/rfc822");
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Richiesta appuntamento");
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Nome paziente: " + id + " " + giorni + " " + "Note: " + note);
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"dottcastellitto@gmail.com"});
            startActivity(mail);
        }
    });

}
}
```

other way is
like

```
        public class Appuntamento extends Activity
        { 

        String paziente;
          boolean lun,mar ,mer,giov,ven;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.appuntamento);
            //riceviamo id e lo mettiamo come nome utente
            final EditText nomePaziente = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nomePaziente);
            Bundle dati = this.getIntent().getExtras();
            nomePaziente.setText(dati.getString("id"));
            final String id = dati.getString("id");
            EditText noteAppuntamento = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noteAppuntamento);
            final String note = noteAppuntamento.getText().toString();

            final CheckBox lunedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxLunedi);
           lunedi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    lun=isChecked;
    //either one above or below
    //lun = lunedi.isChecked();
           }
       }
    );     
            final CheckBox martedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxMartedì);
          martedi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    mar=isChecked;
    //either one above or below
    //mar = martedi.isChecked();
           }
       }
    );     
            final CheckBox mercoledi =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxMercoledi);
             mercoledi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    mer=isChecked;
    //either one above or below
    // mer = mercoledi.isChecked();
           }
       }
    );     
            final CheckBox giovedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxGiovedi);
            giovedi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
     giov=isChecked;
    //either one above or below
    // giov = giovedi.isChecked();
           }
       }
    );     
            final CheckBox venerdi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxVenerdi); 
    venerdi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
     ven=isChecked;
    //either one above or below
    //ven = venerdi.isChecked();
           }
       }
    );     
            Button richiestaAppuntamento =   (Button)     findViewById(R.id.btnRichiestaAppuntamento);
            richiestaAppuntamento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
              //  ven = venerdi.isChecked();
              //  lun = lunedi.isChecked();
               // mar = martedi.isChecked();
               // mer = mercoledi.isChecked();
              //  giov = giovedi.isChecked();
                StringBuilder testoMail = new StringBuilder();
        //your code this is fine if only one selected item info or data you want to send in mail 
                if (lun ){
                 testoMail.append("Lunedì");
                } else if (mar){
                  testoMail.append("Martedì");
                }else if (mer) {
                 testoMail.append("Mercoledì");
                } else if (giov) {
                 testoMail.append("Giovedì");
                } else if (ven) {
                 testoMail.append("Venerdì");
                }
        // if you want all then comment above code and uncomment below code
        /*
                    if (lun ){
                     testoMail.append("Lunedì");
                    } 
                    if (mar){
                      testoMail.append("Martedì");
                    }
                    if (mer) {
                     testoMail.append("Mercoledì");
                    } 
                    if (giov) {
                     testoMail.append("Giovedì");
                    } 
                    if (ven) {
                     testoMail.append("Venerdì");
                    }
        */

              String giorni = testoMail.toString();
                    Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    mail.setType("message/rfc822");
                    mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Richiesta appuntamento");
                    mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Nome paziente: " + id + " " + giorni + " " + "Note: " + note);
                    mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"dottcastellitto@gmail.com"});
                    startActivity(mail);
                }
            });

        }
        }
```

Comment: I tried the first way and it works! Many many thanks!! as I wanted all I used if instead if else. Thanks!